# Plotly: preventing bars on bar chart from changing color based on background color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a set of sales data in a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks similar to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15'],
                  'sales':[1500, 2000, 1300, 2700, 1800, 4500, 2600, 2750, 8000, 1300]})

    date          sales
0   2021-01-04    1500
1   2021-01-05    2000
2   2021-01-06    1300
3   2021-01-07    2700
4   2021-01-08    1800
5   2021-01-11    4500
6   2021-01-12    2600
7   2021-01-13    2750
8   2021-01-14    8000
9   2021-01-15    1300
```

I then plot this data, as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y='sales')

fig.add_hrect(y0=0, y1=2200, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.25)
fig.add_hrect(y0=2200, y1=5000, line_width=0, fillcolor="yellow", opacity=0.25)
fig.add_hrect(y0=5000, y1=10000, line_width=0, fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25)

fig.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the blue vertical bars turn a **purple color** when combined with the red background color.

One workaround might be to paint the red, green, and yellow background colors first, ***then*** to overlay the blue bars.  This way, we're not 'mixing' red and blue, thereby making purple.

Is this possible?  Is there another, better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the option to add `layer='below'` to the `add_hrect`.

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y='sales')

fig.add_hrect(y0=0, y1=2200, line_width=0, fillcolor="red", opacity=0.25, layer='below')
fig.add_hrect(y0=2200, y1=5000, line_width=0, fillcolor="yellow", opacity=0.25, layer='below')
fig.add_hrect(y0=5000, y1=10000, line_width=0, fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, layer='below')
```

Comment: I was not aware of `layer='below'`.  This works beautifully.  Thank you.