# Plotly: Add Inter quantile range to the scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a scatter plot using plotly express. I want to add inter quantile range to the same plot.
I tried to that by creating a line plot, then increasing width as much as inter quantile range and decreasing the opacity to get the expected plot. But it isn't worked.

**Code:**

```
sample = {'columns': ['MM_ln_MM_sn', 'MM_l_MM_s', 'MM_l', 'MM_s_cc', 'date1'],
 'data': [[45, 69880, 99739, 10.33251321021105, '13/06/06'],
  [34, 61116, 91198, 10.4397740050252, '20/06/06'],
  [25, 57215, 88635, 10.73127747285588, '27/06/06'],
  [27, 59326, 90104, 10.52239316239316, '04/07/06'],
  [37, 71884, 101019, 9.317713730155685, '11/07/06'],
  [31, 79271, 105068, 7.955260333789735, '18/07/06'],
  [36, 72907, 96891, 7.598650339791215, '25/07/06'],
  [40, 70609, 95785, 8.256943920605298, '01/08/06'],
  [44, 74318, 100994, 8.630300520548566, '08/08/06'],
  [44, 67890, 94115, 8.369850028883564, '15/08/06'],
  [45, 60305, 87386, 8.845057173932213, '22/08/06'],
  [34, 49529, 80809, 10.16961275493119, '29/08/06'],
  [38, 58222, 87652, 9.196932480828005, '05/09/06'],
  [30, 45940, 76571, 9.86473865575988, '12/09/06'],
  [25, 41593, 72225, 9.400586769453618, '19/09/06'],
  [12, 35324, 68325, 10.21902104744888, '26/09/06'],
  [13, 32453, 66119, 10.19980912850499, '03/10/06'],
  [7, 23064, 62270, 11.72677213164278, '10/10/06'],
  [11, 21829, 64602, 12.9664266767715, '17/10/06'],
  [12, 10179, 54019, 13.22082762863467, '24/10/06']],
 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=sample['index'], columns=sample['columns'], data=sample['data'])

fig1 = px.scatter(df, x="MM_ln_MM_sn", y="MM_l_MM_s",trendline="ols",
             size="MM_l", color="MM_s_cc",
                 hover_name="date1", log_x=True, size_max=30)


x = [df["MM_ln_MM_sn"].values[-1]]
y = [df["MM_l_MM_s"].values[-1]]
fig1.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y,
                  marker=dict(color='black',size=16),
                  showlegend=False
                    )
                )

xval = list(range(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"].min()-20 ,df["MM_ln_MM_sn"].max()+20))
fig2 = px.line(x=xval,y=[np.median(df["MM_l_MM_s"])]*len(xval))

yval = list(range(df["MM_l_MM_s"].min()-int(5*1e4) ,df["MM_l_MM_s"].max()+int(5*1e4)))
fig3 = px.line(y=yval,x=[np.median(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"])]*len(yval))

fig = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data + fig3.data)

fig.update_layout(
     title='Dry Powder Net Indicator',
    xaxis_title='MM Net Number of Traders',
    yaxis_title='MM Net OI',
    showlegend=False)

fig.update_traces(boxmean= True, selector=dict(type='box'))


fig.show()
```

**IQR values:**

```
xq2 = np.percentile(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"], 25)
xq3 = np.percentile(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"], 75)
yq2 = np.percentile(df["MM_l_MM_s"], 25)
yq3 = np.percentile(df["MM_l_MM_s"], 75)
```

**Output:** (Need to add IQR)

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

**Code-V1:**

```
fig.add_hline(y=np.median(df["MM_l_MM_s"]), line_dash="dot", row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="Median", 
              annotation_position="bottom right")

fig.add_vline(x=np.median(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"]), line_dash="dot", row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="Median", 
              annotation_position="bottom right")

fig.add_vrect(x0=xq2, x1=xq3, row="all", col=1,
              annotation_text="decline", annotation_position="top left",
              fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, line_width=0)


fig.add_vrect(x0=yq2, x1=yq3, row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="decline", annotation_position="top left",
              fillcolor="green", opacity=0.25, line_width=0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590020/plotly-preventing-bars-on-bar-chart-from-changing-color-based-on-background-col) will answer your question if your know the ranges. Please also check [add_hrect() and add_vrect()](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/#horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles).

Comment: I suggest to use `add_vline()` and `add_hline()` instead of `line()`

Comment: @shaikmoeed Have you calculated all necessary valus in order to apply those shapes? Like upper and lower levels?

Comment: @vestland Yes, I have calculated all necessary values using `np.percentile` for 25 and 75 ragne.

Comment: @mosc9575 `add_hrect` is give attribute error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_hrect'`

Comment: @shaikmoeed What plotly version are you on?

Comment: Which version do you use? The methods I suggest are `introduced in plotly 4.12`. Maybe you have to update your `plotly` and your `plotly express`. You have also to add `import plotly.express as px`.

Comment: @vestland plotly version : 4.4.1

Comment: @mosc9575 I have made changes, but the plot is not looking as I wanted. Can you please check and correct it?

Comment: @vestland I have updated the version and added the code snippet to my question. Can you please check and correct it?

Comment: You added `add_vrect` twice. One has to be `add_hrect`.

Comment: @mosc9575 I have made those changes, but still, I'm getting very long x-axis.

Comment: Could you please publish your values `xq2`, `xq3`, `yq2`  & `yq3` and also the update your current figure. If it is still wrong, try to comment some parts of the figure. Non  of `add_hline`, `add_vline`, `add_hrect` & `add_vrect` should have any impect on the x-range.

Comment: @mosc9575 When I add `add_vline` or `add_vrect` the x-range is increasing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233228/discussion-between-mosc9575-and-shaik-moeed).

Answer (score 2):

I added this to the end of your code.

```
xq2 = np.percentile(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"], 25)
xq3 = np.percentile(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"], 75)
yq2 = np.percentile(df["MM_l_MM_s"], 25)
yq3 = np.percentile(df["MM_l_MM_s"], 75)

print(xq2, xq3, yq2, yq3)

fig.add_hline(y=np.median(df["MM_l_MM_s"]), line_dash="dot", row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="Median", 
              annotation_position="bottom right")

fig.add_vline(x=np.median(df["MM_ln_MM_sn"]), line_dash="dot", row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="Median", 
              annotation_position="bottom right")

fig.add_vrect(x0=xq2, x1=xq3, row="all", col=1,
              annotation_text="decline", annotation_position="top left", layer='below',
              fillcolor="#CCCCCC", opacity=1, line_width=0)


fig.add_hrect(y0=yq2, y1=yq3, row="all", col="all",
              annotation_text="decline", annotation_position="top left", layer='below',
              fillcolor="#CCCCCC", opacity=1, line_width=0)
```

This is the output I generated.

[image: Plotly figure]

**Comment**
I am posting this, because we thought there could be a bug when using the keywords `annotation_text` and `annotation_position`.

In my little test I couldn't see any thing strange. Everything is working like expected.